# IE don't inherit opacity

Tags: internet-explorer, opacity

I'm stucked into a opacity problem...

I have this HTML structure

```
<body>
  <div id="G_I_Error"></div>
  <div id="main">
    <!-- some stuff -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Then, with JS I modify "main" opacity.

But, with IE8 the child elements of "main" have always the same opacity (100)...

How can I do to make the childrens have the same opacity as "main"?

Comment: What are the elements into your main div ? Can you show us your css and js code ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a few DIV's... something like this:

```
<div class="main" id="main">
  <div class="top">
    <span class="logoNameText">MY WEBSITE</span>
    <form name="li" action="#" method="post">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
  </div>

  <script>launchError(1);<script>
</div>
```

Is a log-in page...

The JS code is pretty simple:

```
function launchError(c){
  t='';
  if(c==1){
t='<span id="Close" onclick="dimiss(1);">x</span><span id="Error"><b>Error opening session</b><br /><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></span>';
  }else if(c==2){
t='<span id="Close" onclick="dimiss(1);">x</span><span id="Error"><b>Error during register: </b><br />Inserted emails don\'t match</span>';
  }else if(c==3){
t='<span id="Close" onclick="dimiss(1);">x</span><span id="Error"><b>Error during register: </b><br />Inserted passwords don\'t match</span>';
  }else if(c==4){
t='<span id="Close" onclick="dimiss(1);">x</span><span id="Error"><b>Error during register: </b><br />Inserted email is already registered</span>';
  }

  if(c<=4){
    document.getElementById('G_I_Error').innerHTML=t;
    setOpacity(document.getElementById('main'), 50);
    document.re.d.setAttribute('onclick', 'voidFunction();');
  }
}


function setOpacity(e,o){
  e.style.opacity=o/100;
  e.style.MozOpacy=o/100;
  e.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+o+')';
}
```

Then, CSS is simple, too.

```
.main{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:auto;width:1000px;}
.top{height:98px;}
.content{top:20px;height:500px;position:relative;}
```

... I hope it helps.